# How do I check if a key has been pressed in TKinter outside the window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a program where it detects if you have clicked a key on your keyboard. I know you can do:

```
def show(key):
    if key == Key.tab:
       print("Click")


with Listener(on_press=show) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

However, I want it to detect a keypress even when the root window isn't selected. For example, let's say I switch my window to Google Chrome. Although the Tkinter window is selected, I want to detect if you were to press 'tab.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a callback whenever a key is pressed using `.on_press()` from [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) module.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

def on_key(event):
    if event.name == "tab":
        key_label.config(text="Click")
        # clear the label after 100ms
        root.after(100, lambda: key_label.config(text=""))

root = tk.Tk()
key_label = tk.Label(root, width=10, font="Arial 24 bold")
key_label.pack(padx=100, pady=50)

keyboard.on_press(on_key)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In this case the `keyboard` module will start a new thread to call your `on_key` function. And you shouldn't call any `tkinter` functions from threads other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk()`.

Answer (score 1):

Download the keyboard module:
pip3 install keyboard

```
import keyboard #Using module keyboard
while True:#making a loop
try: #used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'): #if key 'a' is pressed 
        print('You Pressed A Key!')
        break #finishing the loop
    else:
        pass
except:
    break #if user pressed other than the given key the loop will break
```

or use msvcrt module:
import msvcrt

```
while True:
if msvcrt.kbhit():
    print('CLİCK')



import keyboard#Keyboard module in Python

rk = keyboard.record(until ='q')#It records all the keys until escape is pressed

keyboard.play(rk, speed_factor = 1)#It replay back the all keys
```

Comment: But since its a while loop the Tkinter window won't open until I press 'a'. I want to find a way I can open the Tkinter window, switch to a different window, press 'a' and it should still print. Sorry if I'm phrasing this wrong.

Comment: As long as the program is open and the q key is not pressed, it will give the key that was pressed.

Comment: Tutorial for keyboard module: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLnNPjL1U2g&t=430s

Comment: You actually could put this in a loop using `after()` that way it can run always and not interfere with `mainloop()` or maybe use `threading`

Comment: did You test this with tkinter?